# How to create unique input in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to android development. I have been trying to add unique input inside my android app for every user. I'm currently able tu put user's name variable inside my Firestore, but when I input variable from my second phone it overwrites the first input.

I want every user to have unique input and output inside my app and not intersect with other users data.

My Code:

```
 private DocumentReference docref = db.collection("UserData").document("UserDocuments");

     String name = name_input.getText().toString();

           Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put(NAME_KEY, name);

           docref.update(user);
```

Comment: Show us the code that you are using to add the data to Firestore.

Comment: @AlexMamo definitely forgot to mention the most important part, I updated it. Thank you for reminding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I input variable from my second phone it overwrites the first input.

This is happening because there is no unique identifier between your users. Every user writes data in the same document named  `UserDocuments`. The most common practice, in this case, is to implement [Firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth). Once a user is authenticated, you can use the `uid` to create different user objects in your database. A possible database schema might look like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users (collection)
        |
        --- uidOne (document)
        |    |
        |    --- name: "John Smith"
        |
        --- uidTwo (document)
             |
             --- name: "Peter Max"
```

In this way, you can use the same `update()` method but now you can update the exact user that you want without overwriting the same document.

Comment: Hey Alex, I was unable to see your question until this day, I was active on my second project. First I wanna thank you for answering my question and I wanna say that I successfully implemented google and e-mail authentication. How can I create FireBase uid objects that You mentioned before to insert this name and read it as unique data?

Comment: @NedimKaravdic Simply by using: `String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()`.